# How to upload font file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have files like this `font.ttf` I need to upload them

HTML code:

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.settings.pdf.update') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input type="file" name="file" accept=".ttf" required>
    <button type="submit" class="button green">upload</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function updatePdfFont(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'file' => 'required|file',
    ]);

    // dd($request->all());
    // rename($request->file, "pdf_font.ttf");

    $request->file->store('fonts', 'public');
}

// public disk is a custom one that goes files to public folder
```

The problem that I'm facing now when uploading font it uploaded with no extension like this `wmRey4YaOLaldchlFV1l6GQylbZArc4xmyy2tXnL`

The second thing I need is how can I rename the file before uploading it? like I want to rename file to `pdf_font.ttf`

Answer (score 0):

before this line:
`$request->file->store('fonts', 'public');`
get the file extension like this:

`$file_name = $file->'pdf_font'.getClientOriginalExtension();`

Now store the file with the `$file_name`

Answer (score -1):

In web applications, one of the most common use-cases for storing files is storing user uploaded files such as photos and documents. Laravel makes it very easy to store uploaded files using the store method on an uploaded file instance. Call the store method with the path at which you wish to store the uploaded file:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');
    return $path;
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-uploads

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#specifying-a-file-name